# Search and remove element with elementTree in Python

Tags: python, elementtree

I have an XML document in which I want to search for some elements and if they match some criteria
I would like to delete them

However, I cannot seem to be able to access the parent of the element so that I can delete it

```
file = open('test.xml', "r")
elem = ElementTree.parse(file)

namespace = "{http://somens}"

props = elem.findall('.//{0}prop'.format(namespace))
for prop in props:
    type = prop.attrib.get('type', None)
    if type == 'json':
        value = json.loads(prop.attrib['value'])
        if value['name'] == 'Page1.Button1':
            #here I need to access the parent of prop
            # in order to delete the prop
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can remove child elements with the according `remove` method. To remove an element you have to call its parents `remove` method. Unfortunately `Element` does not provide a reference to its parents, so it is up to you to keep track of parent/child relations (which speaks against your use of `elem.findall()`)

A proposed solution could look like this:

```
root = elem.getroot()
for child in root:
    if child.name != "prop":
        continue
    if True:# TODO: do your check here!
        root.remove(child)
```

PS: don't use `prop.attrib.get()`, use `prop.get()`, as explained [here](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-elementtree-ElementTree.htm#elementtree.ElementTree._ElementInterface.attrib-attribute).

Comment: I see. I am also taking a look at lxml which from what I have read provide access to the element's parent. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, that is correct. lxml provides an `ElementTree` implementation with more features than the interface normally states. The `Element` class  in lxml provides the `getparent()` method to get a reference to a parent Element.

Comment: What if the child element is more than one element deep from the root? What if it's at variable depths?

Comment: "As explained here" - *here* links to *attrib [#]

    (Attribute) Element attribute dictionary. Where possible, use get, set, keys, and items to access element attributes.*,  but that's hardly an explanation.  What is the reason for using `get` over `attrib`?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread but this kept popping up while I was trying to figure out a similar task. I did not like the accepted answer for two reasons:

1) It doesn't handle multiple nested levels of tags.

2) It will break if multiple xml tags are deleted in the same level one-after-another. Since each element is an index of `Element._children` you shouldn't delete while forward iterating.

I think a better more versatile solution is this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
file = 'test.xml'
tree = et.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

def iterator(parents, nested=False):
    for child in reversed(parents):
        if nested:
            if len(child) >= 1:
                iterator(child)
        if True:  # Add your entire condition here
            parents.remove(child)

iterator(root, nested=True)
```

For the OP, this should work - but I don't have the data you're working with to test if it's perfect.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
file = 'test.xml'
tree = et.parse(file)

namespace = "{http://somens}"
props = tree.findall('.//{0}prop'.format(namespace))

def iterator(parents, nested=False):
    for child in reversed(parents):
        if nested:
            if len(child) >= 1:
                iterator(child)
        if prop.attrib.get('type') == 'json':
            value = json.loads(prop.attrib['value'])
            if value['name'] == 'Page1.Button1':
                parents.remove(child)

iterator(props, nested=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use xpath to select an Element's parent.

```
file = open('test.xml', "r")
elem = ElementTree.parse(file)

namespace = "{http://somens}"

props = elem.findall('.//{0}prop'.format(namespace))
for prop in props:
    type = prop.get('type', None)
    if type == 'json':
        value = json.loads(prop.attrib['value'])
        if value['name'] == 'Page1.Button1':
            # Get parent and remove this prop
            parent = prop.find("..")
            parent.remove(prop)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax

**Except** if you try that it doesn't work: http://elmpowered.skawaii.net/?p=74

So instead you have to:

```
file = open('test.xml', "r")
elem = ElementTree.parse(file)

namespace = "{http://somens}"
search = './/{0}prop'.format(namespace)

# Use xpath to get all parents of props    
prop_parents = elem.findall(search + '/..')
for parent in prop_parents:
    # Still have to find and iterate through child props
    for prop in parent.findall(search):
        type = prop.get('type', None)
        if type == 'json':
            value = json.loads(prop.attrib['value'])
            if value['name'] == 'Page1.Button1':
                parent.remove(prop)
```

It is two searches and a nested loop. The inner search is only on Elements known to contain props as first children, but that may not mean much depending on your schema.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using lxml module

```
from lxml import etree

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
for e in root.findall('.//{http://some.name.space}node'):
parent = e.getparent()
for child in parent.find('./{http://some.name.space}node'):
    try:
        parent.remove(child)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that every child must have a parent, I'm going to simplify @kitsu.eb's example. f using the findall command to get the children and parents, their indices will be equivalent.

```
    file = open('test.xml', "r")
    elem = ElementTree.parse(file)

    namespace = "{http://somens}"
    search = './/{0}prop'.format(namespace)

    # Use xpath to get all parents of props    
    prop_parents = elem.findall(search + '/..')

    props = elem.findall('.//{0}prop'.format(namespace))
    for prop in props:
            type = prop.attrib.get('type', None)
            if type == 'json':
                value = json.loads(prop.attrib['value'])
                if value['name'] == 'Page1.Button1':
                    #use the index of the current child to find
                    #its parent and remove the child
                    prop_parents[props.index[prop]].remove(prop)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also used XPath for this issue, but in a different way:

```
root = elem.getroot()    
elementName = "YourElement"
#this will find all the parents of the elements with elementName
for elementParent in root.findall(".//{}/..".format(elementName)):
   #this will find all the elements under the parent, and remove them
   for element in elementParent.findall("{}".format(elementName)):
      elementParent.remove(element)
```

Comment: Or use `".//*[{}]".format(elementName)"`: then you're looking for the parent node, and removing the child is easy.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use an XPath expression for this kind of filtering. Unless I know otherwise, such an expression must be applied at the root level, which means I can't just get a parent and apply the same expression on that parent. However, it seems to me that there is a nice and flexible solution that should work with any supported XPath, as long as none of the sought nodes is the root. It goes something like this:

```
root = elem.getroot()
# Find all nodes matching the filter string (flt)
nodes = root.findall(flt)
while len(nodes):
    # As long as there are nodes, there should be parents
    # Get the first of all parents to the found nodes
    parent = root.findall(flt+'/..')[0]
    # Use this parent to remove the first node
    parent.remove(nodes[0])
    # Find all remaining nodes
    nodes = root.findall(flt)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like only to add a comment on the accepted answer, but my lack of reputation doesn't allow me to. I wanted to add that it is important to add `.findall("*")`to the iterator to avoid issues, as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

> Note that concurrent modification while iterating can lead to problems, just like when iterating and modifying Python lists or dicts. Therefore, the example first collects all matching elements with root.findall(), and only then iterates over the list of matches.

Therefore, in the accepted answer the iteration should be `for child in root.findal("*"):`instead of `for child in root:`. Not doing so made my code skip some elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you stumble on this question because you want to search and remove elements with ElementTree

- using built in xml module (not lxml)
- being as flexible as ElementTree.findall (using xpath subset)
- directly referencing the elements to be deleted, not the parents
- work on any nesting level
- work even if found elements are nested in other found elements

Then this function may help. It builts and uses a map from the element to its parents.

```py
import itertools
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def deleteall(root: ElementTree.Element, match, namespaces=None):
    parent_by_child=dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        ((child, element) for child in element) for element in root.iter()))

    for element in root.findall(match, namespaces):
        parent_by_child[element].remove(element)
```

Additional checks as required in the original post can be done by a Callable provided as additional argument:

```py
import itertools
from typing import Callable
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def deleteall(
    root: ElementTree.Element,
    match,
    namespaces=None,
    deletion_criteria: Callable[[ElementTree.Element], bool]=lambda x: True
):
    parent_by_child=dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        ((child, element) for child in element) for element in root.iter()))
    for element in root.findall(match, namespaces):
        if deletion_criteria(element):
            parent_by_child[element].remove(element)
```

Further extensions like providing both the element and its parent to the deletion criteria would be possible.