# Python : Remove an element but not its children from xml?

Tags: python, xml, element, children

I want to remove element but not its children. I tried with this code, but my code remove its children also.

**code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root.findall('item'):
    root.remove(item)

print(ET.tostring(root))
>>> <root>
    </root>
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <item>
        <data>
            <number>01</number>
            <step>one</step>
        </data>
    </item>
</root>
```

**expected outcome**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <data>
        <number>01</number>
        <step>one</step>
    </data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move all children of `item` to `root` before removing

```
for item in root.findall('item'):
    for child in item:
        root.append(child)
    root.remove(item)

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

the code results in

```
<root>
   <data>
       <number>01</number>
       <step>one</step>
   </data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the element with `data` tag, remove it and extend the element's parent with element's children.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

data = """
<root>
    <item>
        <data>
            <number>01</number>
            <step>one</step>
        </data>
    </item>
</root>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(data)

def iterparent(tree):
    for parent in tree.iter():
        for child in parent:
            yield parent, child

tree = etree.fromstring(data)
for parent, child in iterparent(tree):
    if child.tag == "data":
        parent.remove(child)
        parent.extend(child)

print((etree.tostring(tree)))
```

will output

```xml
<root>
    <item>
        <number>01</number>
        <step>one</step>
    </item>
</root>
```

Adapted from [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498394/remove-a-node-from-etree-but-leaving-child) for your particular use case.